# Order of Double Coset

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am working on a **homework problem** (so don't just give me the answer) from Herstein's *Topics in Algebra*, which goes as follows:

> If $G$ is a finite group, show that the number of elements in the
>   double coset $AxB$ is $$\dfrac{o(A)o(B)}{o(A\cap xBx^{-1})}$$

It makes sense to me, but my attempts at a proof seem to fall short of undeniability. I have been trying to show that $o(A \cap x B x^{-1})$ equals the number of duplicate terms in the list of all possible products of an element from $A$ and an element from $xB$.

Suppose $a_0 \in A \cap xBx^{-1}$. Then $\exists b_0 \in B : a_0 = x b_0 x^{-1}$. In the list of products of the form $axb, a \in A, b \in B$, any term involving $a_0$ will be of the form $a_0 x b = x b_0 x^{-1} x b = x b_0 b$ for some $b \in B$. But then this list is just the left coset $xB$, which is already accounted for in the product list of $AxB$ by setting $a=e$.

This is where I run into trouble. I can't seem to crystallize this argument. Am I going about this the right way? And if you see how I should extend this argument, can you nudge me in the right direction?

Thanks Math.SE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:** I didn't notice that "don't just give me the answer" in the first version of my answer. The following are some hints.

Firstly, the formula 
$$o(HK)=\frac{o(H)o(K)}{o(H\cap K)}$$
**holds for subgroups** $H$ and $K$ of $G$, but may **not hold for subsets** $H$ and $K$ of $G$.

Secondly, note that

$$o(AxB)=o(AxBx^{-1}).$$

Comment: why last equality holds. What 1-1 onto map we will define between two sets

Comment: @Sushil: The natural 1-1 and onto map is $axb\leftrightarrow axbx^{-1}$ for $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.

Comment: @23rd and   how you use the equality  $o(HK)=\frac{o(H)o(K)}{o(H\cap K)}$ if  para $H=A$ and $K=xBx^{-1}$ if not necessarily $xBx^{-1}$ is a subgroup?

Comment: @Sushil    how you use the equality  $o(HK)=\frac{o(H)o(K)}{o(H\cap K)}$ if  para $H=A$ and $K=xBx^{-1}$ if not necessarily $xBx^{-1}$ is a subgroup?

Comment: A and B are given subgroups while defining double cosets. I think OP forgot to mention it @RoinerSeguraCubero

Comment: @Sushil but $xBx^{-1}$ is not subgroup? How you use the equiality then?

Comment: B subgroup implies  xBx−1 subgroup

Answer (score 2):

This is a very nice formula:

$$|HK|=\frac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}.$$

There are a couple of beautiful proofs, suggested intrinsically by its form, that I will hint at:

- **Coset spaces**. You probably know the formula $|G/H|=|G|/|H|$; in other words you know how to interpret a ratio of two group orders as the size of a coset space when the denominator group is contained in the numerator group. There are four quantities appearing in the desired formula, arranged in the form $A=BC/D$. Can you rearrange this so that the equation involves expressions of the form $|X|/|Y|$? Now interpret the expressions as spaces of either left or right cosets. Exhibit an explicit bijection between these two coset spaces.
- **Group actions**. If $G$ acts on a set $X$, then the *orbit-stabilizer formula* asserts that the size of an orbit $Gx$ is equal to the index of $x$'s stabilizer in $G$. You know $|H||K|=|H\times K|$. Can you think of a group action on a set which yields the desired formula from orbit-stabilizer?

Answer (score 0):

I am reading "Topics in Algebra 2nd Edition" by I. N. Herstein.
This problem is Problem 40 on p.49 in Herstein's book.
I solved this problem as follows:

> $\#AxB=o(A(xBx^{-1}))=\frac{o(A)o(xBx^{-1})}{o(A\cap xBx^{-1})}=\frac{o(A)o(B)}{o(A\cap xBx^{-1})}$ by THEOREM 2.5.1 on p.45 in Herstein's book.
> Note that $xBx^{-1}$ is a subgroup of $G$ for any $x\in G$ and $o(B)=o(xBx^{-1})$ for any $x\in G$.
> Note that $G\ni y\mapsto yx^{-1}\in G$ is injective, so $\#AxB=o(A(xBx^{-1}))$.